# Fast Approximate Spectral Clustering in Practice?

Tags: clustering, unsupervised-learning, spectral-analysis

Spectral clustering takes $O(n^3)$ time. Over the last fifteen years, a huge number of heuristics have been published on speeding up spectral clustering (e.g. Nystrom method, PCA, sample size reduction, or methods like [http://www.math.umassd.edu/~dyan/2009KDD.pdf](http://www.math.umassd.edu/%7Edyan/2009KDD.pdf) or https://www.ibm.com/blogs/research/2018/08/spectral-clustering/).

However, it appears that the spectral clustering method in SKLearn is still cubic time. Spectral clustering on the most widely cited tutorial still uses an $O(n^3)$ run time on dense affinity graphs, and most of the faster methods don't appear to be heavily tested on classical clustering datasets.

Is there a "gold standard" for fast spectral clustering?  Or is the right strategy to try out every one of the many fast spectral clustering methods?